# Switch back to Xfce from Gnome (login screen/file dialog)

Tags: gnome, xfce

I'm running Lubuntu with Xfce. I installed `ubuntu-desktop-minimal` to test some software on Gnome. Now, the login screen is the Gnome type login screen. I can select Xfce as the desktop environment. But what's annoying is, the file dialog has changed. The behavior of this file dialog is not what I'm used to (lighter color theme, doesn't even support multi-select files). How can I switch completely back to Lubuntu/Xfce?

[image: The new file dialog]

Comment: Generally speaking, it is never a good idea to mix desktop environments. Yes, technically it is possible, but there are multiple possibilities of interfering which can leas to all kinds of weird behavior and conflicts. Running "Xfce on Lubuntu" is already strange - why not using Xubuntu straight away?
Anway, what you could try is to run `sudo apt remove ubuntu-desktop-minimal` followed by `sudo apt autopurge`. This should remove the GNOME Desktop, but no guarantees that no artifacts are left or - although it is unlikely, but not impossible - that you system is left in a weird state.

Comment: You've not provided any release details; which to me are the starting point. I'm a *lover* of multiple DEs on my machine, and my current box has all of Lubuntu (LXQt), Xubuntu (Xfce) & Ubuntu Desktop (GNOME) installed (*for starters!*)... but each DE allows you to change default GTK2/GTK3/GTK4/Qt5 themes which impact all DEs & not just whichever you're using, so when making theme changes ensure they're [*visually/aesthetically*] compatible with all.. and if you want reverse changes; just undo whatever change(s) you made (*this is unclear to me from your description*).

Comment: Ubuntu releases still have GTK2 apps; thus all DEs handle theming of GTK2 (*even though deprecated*), older releases won't have the GTK4... so you may not have all options I mentioned, but you didn't provide release details.. thus my prior comment assumes you're using my current release (*which has GTK2, GTK3, & GTK4 app setups plus of course Qt5*).  FYI: I'd call your system a Ubuntu with Xfce system (*not Lubuntu with Xfce*), as at their core, all *flavors* of Ubuntu are really just Ubuntu systems (*let alone Lubuntu being a Qt5 system makes little sense mixing with Xfce or GTK3*)

Comment: I already tried removing `ubuntu-desktop-minimal` before, but it removed only a tiny package of a few kb, vs. the +400MB of packages it installed. Now, I did `sudo apt autopurge` according to @noisefloor suggestion. This helped changing the login screen back to an Xfce login screen. However, that pesky file dialog is still there. How can I change it back? My Ubuntu version is 22.04 with Xfce 4.16.